# Ваша идея об архитектуре?

Tags: php

Основная цель системы - обнаружение страны пользователя, который посещает веб-сайт. Она работает для любой страницы, которую может открыть пользователь. Если страна будет обнаружена значение вставляется в сессии PHP, затем перенаправляет на главную страницу. Если страна не была обнаружена, то добавляется значения по умолчанию в сессии и делается переадресация также.

Проблема в том, когда я пытаюсь поделиться ссылкой с помощью любой социальной сети, я всегда получаю главную страницу, потому что срабатывает перенаправление, и социальной бот не распознает, какая страница была первая, чтобы захватить.

Что вы думаете об архитектуре, чтобы изменить?

Comment: Перенаправлять-то зачем?

Comment: Я тоже не понял, зачем перенаправлять пользователя на главную? 
Например, я зашел посмотреть описание конкретного телевизора и тут меня перекидывает на главную - в чем прикол?

Comment: Ошибся. Перенаправляет на туже страницу, которую запрашивал

Comment: да все просто - организовать отток от магазина. что  бы пользователи не приходили:)

Comment: Один фиг Ваш вопрос непонятен.

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, а мой вопрос и не про конкретный адрес перенаправления. Зачем вообще перенаправялть пользователя?